# Joomla post requests

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, form

I'm trying to make an android application and so i want to connect it directly to my Joomla website, i want to send some post requests but they are getting denied, I'm not asking for any help regarding Android, im just asking for anything regarding POST requests
We all know that Joomla has CSRF protection which creates a hidden form with a random name and a value, is there a way i can get the name and the value of that form, so that i can add it with my post request and thank you for your time.

Comment: The usual way is to do a GET to get the Joomla form (including the token in a hidden field), then do a POST to send the form data including the token. Is there a reason why you can't do that?

Comment: @RobbieJackson yes, our college website is crappy and when many people login to it to see there grades once we know that they're out, the website becomes unable to handle this ton of requests so it turns off, it's hard accessing it and viewing your grades, so i thiught of creating an app where it monitors thr website snd the change in html, then logs it in, after it changes its content, i would know that new grades were added.

Comment: I have to also mention that our college administration never tells us that new grades were added, so one can only know that new grades were added if he logs into the website by mistake, thats the main reason why am making this app, to notify me of new grades

Comment: OK, the answer is still the same then. You should emulate a browser by sending an HTTP GET to the website, capture the returned token and send it with the data in the POST. You could do this with the login form to send usr/pwd. However, there's probably an easier way to do that though than developing an android app, eg curl? And if a lot of people are automatically doing this regularly to an overloaded server it's probably only going to make things worse I fear.

Comment: @RobbieJackson the app is going to be used only by me, not by my colleagues, and Joomla, will it return the token with a get request and how can i get it, is there a specific file or a way or code snippet or anything that can help?

Comment: @user have you considered making a TRIGGER in the appropriate table, so that after a row is added a script is executed (whatever you need to happen)?  Writing a new app just to sniff for changes seems like too much overhead, plus it puts a human component into the work flow.  Find a way to detect the changes precisely when they happen and automate the process so that there is no middle [hu]man.

Comment: This question risks being "Too Broad" or "Opinion-based" or "Not Joomla-specific" because there will be a number of ways to accomplish what you require.  I'll welcome you just the same.  Please take our [tour] and tell us a little about yourself in your Profile.

Comment: When you do the GET you will get back an HTML document. You want to look for a <form> element and inside that look for something like <input type="hidden" name=" ... a string of hex digits ..." value="1"> which is the token you need to send back. However, there are likely to be more things you need to set, such as "task" parameter. I would recommend you use the developer tools within a browser and examine the HTTP request/response pairs, and see what you have to emulate. You'll probably have to handle redirects (status 301) getting returned as well, for example.

Comment: @RobbieJackson thank you for this wonderful comment, i did what u requested but unfortunately the every GET request seems to give me back a different token so it didn't work

Comment: @RobbieJackson i was able to get every piece of information that was being sent back to the server but never was able to send the token along it, this is because ever GET request seems to give me back a new token

Comment: Tokens are dependent upon the session, new session means new token. And the setting for what, precisely, constitutes a session and where that information is stored is up to the server admin. Getting a new token for every GET makes me wonder if your app is unable to store the session and return it the way the server wants it. (I don't know if it's worth pointing out that the function of your app (POSTing without using the form) is precisely the kind of behavior that CSRF protection is *designed* to stop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was me not adding the Cookie manager at the dtart of the code, as such for every get request to the server i received a new Token, and so after adding the Cookie manager i was able to get a token which was still the same after each Get request and so I was able to send a Post request and login through a mobile app, thank you alot for all of your help

Comment: If you have resolved your own question, please award your answer the big green tick so that the system stops bumping this page.